# Add Foreign Key to the Table as a column

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables as below:

Table name: table_1

| ID | studentId | Date | enrolled | parent name | parents annual income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 14:39:15 | enrolled | ABC | 12345 |
| 2 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 14:39:06 | not-enrolled | ABC | 10345 |
| 3 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | not-enrolled | ABC | 1467 |

I am working on refactoring this table as it has some flaws and redundant data. Also, the date is mentioned in this table as VARCAR(20).

I want to refactor it into 2 tables as below:

**Table A** --Only 1 entry for each student ID, the first date when entry was made in the table, the latest enrolled status of the student, and parent name (made the entries in the table_1 bold)

Table name: table_2

| ID | studentId | strat_date | enrolled | parent name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | enrolled | ABC |

**Table B** -- The rest of the history data

Table name: table_3

| ID | studentId_1 | Date | parents annual income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:15 | 12345 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:06 | 10345 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | 1467 |

The "ID" column in the "table_2" table is the PRIMARY KEY.
The "studentId_1 " column in the "table_3" table is a FOREIGN KEY.

I know how to create table_2.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2 (studentId, `start_date`, `status`, `parent name`)
SELECT studentId, MIN(`Date`), MIN(enrolled), `parent name`
FROM table_1
GROUP BY studentId, `parent name`;
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

Which gives an output:

| ID | studentId | strat_date | enrolled | parent name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | enrolled | ABC |

How do I create table_3 as it has "FOREIGN KEY" in the table as below:

| ID | studentId_1 | Date | parents annual income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:15 | 12345 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:06 | 10345 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | 1467 |

Answer (score 1):

- MIN(enrolled) is kludgy.  It works only because of string choices and comparison.
- BUG!  `MIN(`Date`), MIN(enrolled)` cannot be trusted to get data from the same row.  You have a "groupwise-max" problem; see the tag.
- You need INDEXes; FKs are optional.
- `ID` on table_3 is unnecessary; the PK can be `PRIMARY KEY(student_id, date)`
- Do use `DATETIME`, not `VARCHAR`.
- Table_2 does not need `ID`; `PRIMARY KEY(student_id)` is really what you need.

Since you seem to be building `students` (`table_2`) and `income_history` (`table_3`) from `table_1`, these two steps might work:

```
INSERT INTO students (...)
    SELECT ... FROM table_1
        WHERE enrolled = 'enrolled';
INSERT INTO income_history (...)
    SELECT ... FROM table_1;
```

(If there are more options for `enrolled` or a student can be "enrolled" twice or ..., then the above won't work.)

Comment: for students table, with enrolled=`enrolled` condition, I would get the date of enrolled row. What I am interested in is the first date the entry was made for that student.

Comment: If there is only one `'enrolled'` row, then use `WHERE enrolled = 'enrolled'`, not min()

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    ID INT,
    studentId INT,
    `Date` DATETIME,
    enrolled VARCHAR(255),
    `parent name` VARCHAR(255),
    `parents annual income` INT
);
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES
(1, 12345,  '2022/01/13 14:39:15',  'enrolled', 'ABC',  12345),
(2, 12345,  '2022/01/13 14:39:06',  'not-enrolled', 'ABC',  10345),
(3, 12345,  '2022/01/13 8:03:44',   'not-enrolled', 'ABC',  1467),
(4, 67890,  '2022/01/12 14:39:15',  'enrolled', 'DEF',  12345),
(5, 67890,  '2022/01/14 14:39:06',  'not-enrolled', 'DEF',  10345),
(6, 67890,  '2022/01/14 8:03:44',   'not-enrolled', 'DEF',  1467);
SELECT * FROM table_1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentId INT,
    `start_date` DATETIME,
    `status` VARCHAR(255),
    `parent name` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE (studentId)
);
CREATE TABLE table_3 (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentId_Id INT,
    `Date` DATETIME,
    enrolled VARCHAR(255),
    `parents annual income` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_studentId_Id  FOREIGN KEY (studentId_Id) REFERENCES table_2 (ID) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

To Insert the data into table_2 from table_1:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2 (studentId, `start_date`, `status`, `parent name`)
SELECT studentId, MIN(`Date`), MIN(enrolled), `parent name` 
FROM table_1
GROUP BY studentId, `parent name`;
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

To Insert the data into table_3 from table_1 in relation with table_2:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 ( studentId_Id, `Date`, enrolled, `parents annual income`)
SELECT t1.ID, t2.`Date`, t2.enrolled, t2.`parents annual income` 
FROM table_2 AS t1, table_1 as t2
WHERE t1.studentId = t2.studentId;
SELECT * FROM table_3;
```